# promise.then is cancelled after calling controller more than once consecutive times,only last returns the data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

My problem is that, I want three separate instances of controller, I am calling it from the html.

my controller is like this

```
app.controller("overallCtrlDemo", function($scope,$rootScope,overAllService,lookupService,uiGmapGoogleMapApi)    {

    var promise=overAllService.getOverAll();
    promise.then(function(data){
        $scope.timeSeries1 = $rootScope.helpers.d3FormatJsonDualAxis(data.data);
        $scope.generic = $scope.timeSeries1;
        $scope.sunBurst = $rootScope.helpers.d3FormatSunburst(data.data);
    })

})
```

and I have three directives in html say

1. timeseries1 (uses timeseries1 data)
2. generic (uses generic data)
3. sunBurst (uses sunBurst data)

But when html renders it calls the controller three times but 
promise.then function returns status 1 for the last call only. she the image below

```
<div id="topProduct-graph" class="chart no-padding"  ng-controller="overallCtrlDemo">
    <topproducts id = "topProducts" data-role="concentric" data-width=400 data-height=400  data-thickness=13 val=topProducts style="position:absolute;"></topproducts>
</div>

<div class="trendMap" style="width:1213px;" ng-controller="overallCtrlDemo">
    <generictimeseries id="genericTimeseries" val="generic" saleorquantity="saleOrQuantity"></generictimeseries>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Afaik a controller in Angular is always called once. Maybe you need a directive?

Comment: see my edits , its some other problem

Comment: where does the `console.log` come from?

Comment: I put console.log(promise) in the controller